# MS Access query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I am using MS access.
I have a table named CHANGES having columns

```
( CNO (int) , TNO (int), DATE_C).
```

I want to write an SQL query which displays recent date and group it only by CNO. But I also want to display TNO.

```
SELECT tno, cno, max(date_c)
FROM changes
WHERE [Date_c] In (SELECT [date_c] FROM changes  WHERE [date_c]<=[Enter date])
GROUP BY cno;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are about seven ways to do this in SQL (because there always is :) and is an oft asked question on Stackoverflow. Here's one: (I've omitted your `date_c <= [Enter date]` parameter for clarity and because I can't test -- I'm not using the Access interface!):

```
SELECT DISTINCT C1.tno, C1.cno, 
       DT1.c_most_recent_date
  FROM changes AS C1
       INNER JOIN (
                   SELECT C2.cno, 
                          MAX(C2.c_date) AS c_most_recent_date
                     FROM changes AS C2
                    GROUP
                       BY C2.cno
                  ) AS DT1 
          ON C1.cno = DT1.cno;
         AND C1.c_date = DT1.c_most_recent_date;
```

And here's another:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C1.tno, C1.cno, 
       C1.c_date AS c_most_recent_date
  FROM changes AS C1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                   SELECT *
                     FROM changes AS C2
                    WHERE C2.cno = C1.cno
                          AND C1.c_date < C2.c_date
                  );
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was a great help :) It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

That makes no sense. You cannot show `TNO` if it could be different for same `CNO` if you are grouping for `CNO`. If you want to show ANY `TNO`, you could do this:

```
SELECT FIRST(tno), cno, max(date_c)
FROM changes
WHERE [Date_c] In (SELECT [date_c] FROM changes  WHERE [date_c]<=[Enter date])
GROUP BY cno;
```

or this:

```
SELECT LAST(tno), cno, max(date_c)
FROM changes
WHERE [Date_c] In (SELECT [date_c] FROM changes  WHERE [date_c]<=[Enter date])
GROUP BY cno;
```

But usually you want to group by both, if you want to display both. (even if you said you don't want to).

Comment: It makes sense to me and I'll try to explain how :) Consider a 'history' table of customer's names with columns `{customer_ID, customer_name, start_date, end_date}` with a sequenced key to prevent overlapping periods for the same `customer_ID` and a regular key on `(customer_ID, customer_name)` (business rule = can't reuse a former name). To find when the most recent name became effective, we could group by `customer_ID` and find the `MAX(start_date)` *then* join back to the table to find the `customer_name` for that `start_date`. There are other ways, of course...

Comment: ...Grouping by `customer_ID` and `customer_name` is not what is wanted because because that would merely create one group for each row in this case because it is a key.